# Insert data into MySQL via PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this db table where I want to store about 100-500 different jokes (small jokes max 500 characters).

```
CREATE TABLE  `jokes` (
 `Num` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `Text` TEXT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

What method I should use for the fastest upload to the db my jokes? 
One of these website's tutorials should be fine for me? 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm

Thanks

Comment: "for the fastest upload" --- as a newbie you need to get it working first. Then optimize **only if necessary**. So - implement it any way you can understand then decide if it's fast enough for you or not.

Comment: You speak about just 100-500 jokes, and on such small amounts of data the method of insertion won't cause noticeably speed difference.  If instead you meant 100k to 500k jokes, you may want to look at [some best practices for bulk insertion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html).  But reread @zerkms' advice - focus on working towards a *correct* and *working* result first.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through full cycle.

Comment: You would be best off using the w3 schools tutorial, as the methods used in the tutorials point link are deprecated. PDO is another driver which may work for you, shown here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

Comment: **NO, PLEASE STAY AWAY FROM THAT w3schools TUTORIAL AS FAR AS POSSIBLE**. You wonder why? That "tutorial" teaches you how to write HORRIBLY BAD code with SQL INJECTION HOLES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question possibly is : What way can I Insert 100's of text items ( possibly from a file ) into Database table .

If the above is the case , the below algorithm could help :

`(1)` Put all the jokes into a text file one joke per line .
`(2)` Using PHP's [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function , get all the lines in to an array :

```
$lines = file("jokes_file.txt");
```

`(3)` Then iterate through the lines and process and Insert into Database Table .

```
foreach( $lines as $line )
{
    echo( $line );
//  Process and Insert into Database Table
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will go through both methods, one-by-one and this algorithm.